# Is it possible to use a roslyn/csc.exe from a different path than bin/roslyn?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

Is it possible to use Roslyn from a different location?

We have a group policy blocking executing files from the website's path, and so Roslyn's invocation of `bin/roslyn/csc.exe` is causing issue.  If we can install Roslyn's files somewhere else on the disk and point to it, everything would work and I wouldn't have to fight the security people.

I can't find any way to do so, though, the magic path roslyn/csc.exe seems built in somewhere.

Comment: Do you mean to allow use the roslyn from another location during build from msbuild or visual studio?

Comment: Neither.  I mean to use roslyn when a cshtml/aspx page is hit and compiled for the first time.